# Making ReSharper's code formatting take into account `this` and `await`

Tags: formatting, resharper

I have VS with ReSharper installed. I have configured ReSharper to pull blocks back so that they align with the line above. This is what it looks like without `await this.`:

[image]

This is how it looks like with `await this.`:

[image]

How can I make it pool the lambda block back to the beginning of `await` so that it looks like this:

[image]